# Using CASE WHEN on boolean columns

Tags: postgresql

This is Postgres 8.x. Speicifcally Redshift.

Table has all FALSE in all the 3 columns. However, when I run this query, it returns as if all are `TRUE`.

```
SELECT
count(CASE WHEN facebook THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
, count(CASE WHEN instagram THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
, count(CASE WHEN twitter THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM public.sampletable
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've also tried `CASE WHEN facebook = TRUE`

I've made sure the cells aren't NULL or anything as well

Comment: use `sum()` instead. count just checks if there's something that's countable (e.g. not null). `0` counts exactly the same as `1`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Do you know if it's possible to sum all 3 columns without a subquery?

Comment: you don't have any subqueries there.

Comment: I know, but I'm trying to do something along the lines of `sum(CASE WHEN facebook THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, CASE WHEN twitter THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, CASE WHEN instagram THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` but am getting a `function sum(integer, integer, integer)` error. So I'm thinking of doing a subquery to achieve this

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN facebook THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +  CASE WHEN twitter THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN instagram THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` **Simple `+` do the job**

Comment: sum doesn't accept multiple arguments. do `sum(a+b+c)`, instead of `sum(a,b,c)`

Comment: Yep, just realized that. Thanks fellas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `COUNT` count `1` and `0` the same. One way is to change the values you want to avoid to `NULL`

```
SELECT
  count(CASE WHEN facebook  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
, count(CASE WHEN instagram THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
, count(CASE WHEN twitter   THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
FROM public.sampletable

SELECT
   count(CASE WHEN facebook  THEN 1 END) -- ELSE NULL is default so you can skip
  ,count(CASE WHEN instagram THEN 1 END)
  ,count(CASE WHEN twitter   THEN 1 END)
FROM public.sampletable
```

or as [`Marc B`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) proposed in comment use `SUM`:

```
SELECT
 SUM(CASE WHEN facebook THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
,SUM(CASE WHEN instagram THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
,SUM(CASE WHEN twitter THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM public.sampletable
```

**EDIT:**

If you need combined sum you can use:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN facebook THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN twitter THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN instagram THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

**EDIT 2**

This answer is inspired by [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33354097/5070879). You can simply cast data:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(facebook AS INT)),
       SUM(CAST(instagram AS INT)),
       SUM(CAST(twitter AS INT)),
       SUM(CAST(facebook AS INT) + CAST(instagram AS INT) + CAST(twitter AS INT))
FROM sampletable;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5eb5b/5/0)**</kbd>

Comment: count is an aggregate function. It COUNTs the number of rows returned, not their values. SUM adds all the VALUEs of the rows. Can't edit because there are too many pending edits.

Answer (score 3):

You can use simple cast to integer:

```
select
    sum(facebook::int) facebook,
    sum(instagram::int) instagram,
    sum(twitter::int) twitter,
    sum(facebook::int+ instagram::int+ twitter::int) total
from public.sampletable;
```

Comment: This is much simpler than the cumbersome `case` syntax in the accepted answer.

Comment: Good point, casting data for true -1 false - 0 is good approach. I allowed myself update my answer too. Anyway +1 :)

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I am not from Postgresql world so I would use approach I suggested. The point of view dependent of what are you familliar with for example with MySQL you don't need to do anything: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1836/1/0. Anyway I also wanted to answer why OP original query doesn't work